# how to do Oauth authentication for 7 digital api method in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth, 7digital

I have to access one api method from 7 digital api and that method must need to be authenticated before use it . Link for **track/ stream** method is [track/stream method](http://api.7digital.com/1.2/static/documentation/7digitalpublicapi.html#track/stream).
I am not getting how exactly to do it i searched a lot but not getting proper way to do .

Answer (score 2):

7digital has a sample OAuth signing tool you can take a look at here:

http://7digital.github.io/oauth-reference-page/

It's all in javascript so you can pick through how to sign a request. Can you provide what you have so far and any errors you're getting?